# Select usando Enum

Tags: javascript, angular, material

Tenho um formulario onde um dos campos é um select, e esse select é um enum, eu consigo popular ele mas não consigo enviar o valor, sempre vai com valor 0 quando faço o post.
Eu queria um select com duas opçoes

HTML:

```
<form class="mat-dialog-content" (ngSubmit)="(submit)" #formControl="ngForm">

  <div class="form">
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
      <textarea matInput #input class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name" required></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select matNativeControl required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of (editoriaTipo | keys)" [value]="item.key" [(ngModel)]="data.type">{{ item.value }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button [type]="submit" [disabled]="!formControl.valid" [mat-dialog-close]="1" (click)="confirmAdd()">
        Savar
      </button>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancelar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Service:

```
  addEditorias(editorias: Editorias): void {
    this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL_Ed, editorias).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dialogData = editorias;
        // this.editoriaService.showToaster("Successfully added", 3000);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // this.editoriaService.showToaster(
        //   "Error occurred. Details: " + err.name + " " + err.message,
        //   8000
        // );
      }
    );
  }
```

Enum:

```
export enum EditoriaType {
  programa = 1,
  editoria = 2,
}
```

Objeto:

```
import { EditoriaType } from "../enum/editoria-type";

export interface Editorias {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  type: EditoriaType;
  dataDeCriacao: Date;
  dataDeAtualizacao: Date;
  deletado: boolean;
}
```

Ele tbm dá o erro:
**EditoriaCriarComponent.html:68 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.**

Sempre cadastra assim com o tipo 0, mesmo eu escolhendo:

```
{
name: "1",
type: 0,
id: "950a1854-a66d-43cd-0bef-08d671c5dec9",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

você pode tentar utilizar dessa forma:

```
  ...

  listaEditoria = EditoriaType;
  keys:any;

  constructor(){
    this.keys = Object.keys( this.listaEditoria ).filter(Number)
    console.log( 'KEys', this.keys )
  }
```

e no select:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let key of keys" [value]="key" >
   {{listaEditoria[ key ]}}
</mat-option>
```

Espero que isso ajude...